# What do device's environment variable list's prefixes (P, N, S, E) mean?

Tags: 14.04, udev

When writing a udev rule, e.g. for a USB storage volume, I can display relevant properties of the plugged in device with either:

```
$ udevadm info -q property -n /dev/sdc1
/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb2/2-3/2-3.1/2-3.1.3/2-3.1.3:1.0/host5/target5:0:0/5:0:0:0/block/sdc/sdc1
sdc1
disk/by-id/usb-Hitachi_HTS541612J9AT00-0:0-part1
disk/by-path/pci-0000:00:1d.7-usb-0:3.1.3:1.0-scsi-0:0:0:0-part1
DEVLINKS=/dev/disk/by-id/usb-Hitachi_HTS541612J9AT00-0:0-part1 /dev/disk/by-path/pci-0000:00:1d.7-usb-0:3.1.3:1.0-scsi-0:0:0:0-part1
DEVNAME=/dev/sdc1
DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb2/2-3/2-3.1/2-3.1.3/2-3.1.3:1.0/host5/target5:0:0/5:0:0:0/block/sdc/sdc1
DEVTYPE=partition
ID_BUS=usb
ID_INSTANCE=0:0
ID_MODEL=HTS541612J9AT00
ID_MODEL_ENC=HTS541612J9AT00\x20
ID_MODEL_ID=0702
ID_PART_ENTRY_DISK=8:32
ID_PART_ENTRY_NUMBER=1
ID_PART_ENTRY_OFFSET=2048
...
```

or

```
$ udevadm info -q all -n /dev/sdc1
P: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb2/2-3/2-3.1/2-3.1.3/2-3.1.3:1.0/host5/target5:0:0/5:0:0:0/block/sdc/sdc1
N: sdc1
S: disk/by-id/usb-Hitachi_HTS541612J9AT00-0:0-part1
S: disk/by-path/pci-0000:00:1d.7-usb-0:3.1.3:1.0-scsi-0:0:0:0-part1
E: DEVLINKS=/dev/disk/by-id/usb-Hitachi_HTS541612J9AT00-0:0-part1 /dev/disk/by-path/pci-0000:00:1d.7-usb-0:3.1.3:1.0-scsi-0:0:0:0-part1
E: DEVNAME=/dev/sdc1
E: DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb2/2-3/2-3.1/2-3.1.3/2-3.1.3:1.0/host5/target5:0:0/5:0:0:0/block/sdc/sdc1
E: DEVTYPE=partition
E: ID_BUS=usb
E: ID_INSTANCE=0:0
E: ID_MODEL=HTS541612J9AT00
E: ID_MODEL_ENC=HTS541612J9AT00\x20
E: ID_MODEL_ID=0702
E: ID_PART_ENTRY_DISK=8:32
E: ID_PART_ENTRY_NUMBER=1
E: ID_PART_ENTRY_OFFSET=2048
...
```

... the obvious difference being the P, N, S, E prefixes in the second case.

I was not able to trace their meaning either in the man pages for `udev` and `udevadm` or using search engines. **Q)** Can someone give me a pointer ?

Comment: Are you sure that you see `P:...` also in the first output? It should not be there...

Comment: @dadexix86: typo corrected. Tx.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is in [`man udevadm`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man8/udevadm.8.html):

```
--query=type
   Query the database for specified type of device data. It needs the
   --path or --name to identify the specified device. Valid queries
   are: name, symlink, path, property, all.
```

So:

- `N`: is for device name in /dev
- `S`: is for symlinks to that device name in /dev
- `P`: is for device path in /sys
- `E`: is for device properties in udev

Comment: @muru, how to do a nice indentation in the block quote to format it like the original manual page fragment?

Comment: That's more difficult if you want to use bold characters. You have to manually use `<pre><code>...</code></pre>` and `<strong>...</strong>`. Not really worth the effort. See edit.

Comment: It had escaped me repeatedly because my version of `man udevadm`on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS does not single out the letters n, s, p and e by making them bold.  Instead the whole word is displayed in bold characters: **name**, **symlink**, **path**, **property**, **all**.  Beyond that I had thought (and also harbored the vague hope) that `E` signaled a PARAMETER accessible to the conditional ENV{PARAMETER}=="value" in udev rules, if only because they are parameter assignments, e.g.: `ID_MODEL=HTS541612J9AT00`. Does this hold ?

Comment: I agree on: `S` symlink in /dev, `P` path in sysfs /sys. and I don't on others: `N` node name in kernel, not in /dev. `E` udev *environment* variable. AFAIK, there is an ambiguity in using `property` in udev doc and posts on the web, sometimes means udev attributes, udev environment variables or both. Btw, the output in OP lists only env vars, notice CAPITAL letters convention.

Comment: +1  @Sneetsher:  I definitely agree with yr above comment. What called my attention is the fact that everything that is preceded by an "E" is capitalized and follows the udev env-var convention. I may have marked that answer as good a little too fast. Is there a consensus on that ?

Comment: @Cbhihe: Well, my `man udevadm` also does not bold that letters, I emphasized them just to make visual connection with capital letters shown by the tool.

Comment: I tried to find a doc or reference for that point. In source code, they called them `properties`, here is [the related function](https://paste.ubuntu.com/14687126/) from [src/udevadm-info.c](https://kernel.googlesource.com/pub/scm/linux/hotplug/udev/+/master/src/udevadm-info.c). So :) you are right about calling them `properties`. However, I would say as`P` is used for `path`, why not `R` or `T` (2nd or 3rd silent letter)! `E` is a vowel letter, to be used means it's mostly in the beginning of the word. I couldn't find a reference for this, I raise my hands :D.

Comment: +1 for the pastebin C function definition. Somehow I'd still be reluctant to see the use of the word "property" in naming a function as proof that that word applies one way or another in the context of the corresponding man page. The author of the code may have used the word in a generic way, which is what I generally tend to do, unless I have a very good reason NOT to. A bit inconclusive, I think, and at this point just a matter of conjecture, so irrelevant for AU. I will approve the given answer, even though there remain a nagging doubt in my mind...